# Changed paper size from letter to legal and size increased

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, rdlc

VS 2010, WPF application, and  a RDLC file. My grid doesn't fit on a letter size page. So I changed the paper size to legal(14 x 11). But when I print the report it increases the grid so that it prints identically to the letter size print out. Ex.: I have 15 columns and in letter size only 11 columns fit on one page. Change to legal size and still only 11 columns fit on the page. The size of the grid increases with the paper size. It is really frustrating. Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you don't have your width/height defined so it will fill the space it has. Define the width and height explicitly. Hope this helped!

Comment: My page size is set to Legal and my Interactive size is set to letter. My width for the Grid is set to the length of all of the columns. Also if of note, I am making these changes in the design view and not programmatically.

Comment: I appreciate your help Paul. Turns out there was code overwriting the rdlc file for some reason. [Insert Taken meme concerning previous programmer]

Answer (score 0):

SO...I was making an update to this report and as it turns out I was doing things right. There was code in a spot outside of the rdlc file that was overwriting what I was trying to do.